# tornadoweb: storing cookies in database and retrieving them

Tags: cookies, python-3.x, tornado

I have two web applications different things, but authentication is  done only by one (using python and tornado), id like to have the second application access the credential of the user transparently, currently I can read the cookie of  a logged in user via  the header:  `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` ,  so how would i access the cookie,  so i can store it (mongodb/redis/anywhere-but-mysql), and retrieve it in the second app?
what I've tried:

```
self.set_secure_cookie('cookie_name') # works i can see the cookie in subsequent request headers
self.get_secure_cookie("cookie_name") # just after setting the cookie returns None
```

what I was thinking is to store the encrypted value and compare it later in the second  application as and when needed, is this sensible? all that i need to do is to ensure the user is
logged in and they exist in out list of users as of the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've managed to set a cookie by one of the servers and then retrieve it on the second? If so, great! That's the trickiest part (imho).

Now there are two ways to go.

1. Store data in the cookie
   Tornado have, as you've noticed, support for secure cookies. This basically mean that you can store data in the cookie and sign it with a secret. If both you servers have the same secret they can verify that the cookie data is not altered and you have successfully distributed data between the two servers. This decentralised  alternative is not suitable if you need to store much data in the session.
2. A shared DB (or an API that the other server can use)
   If you go with this solution you just have to store a session key in the cookie. No need to use secure cookie since it's no data stored there. You simply generate a SSID, e.g. `ssid = uuid.uuid4().hex`, store that in a cookie called something like ssid and also add a record to the DB along with all session data you want to store. I really like Redis for this since you can set the expire on creation and don't have to worry about that anymore, it's pretty fast and the best thing is that there's a nice and easy async lib you can use that plays nice with tornado.